# Issue with creating nested lists

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm a newbie so please bear with me if I've overlooked something basic, but I'm trying to make site that lists yoga classes for my friend's yoga studio, which conceptually should look something like this:

```
Monday

Dynamic Yoga with Mary 6pm

Soft yoga with Susie 8pm

Wednesday

Hatha yoga with Bob 5pm

Hot yoga with Alice 7pm
```

So I want to fetch the list of classes, then see if there is a yoga class on Monday. If there is one I add 'Monday' to the list and all the Monday classes, and so on with all the other days.

Problem:

My code so far appends all the days where there are yoga classes, but then adds all of the classes from the whole week to every day, when they should only add the classes that corresponds to each day.

I.e. when it should be:

```
Monday_list = [Monday, [[Class1Monday],[Class2Monday]]
```

it is instead:

```
Monday_list [Monday, [[CLass1Monday],[CLass2Monday],[CLass1Tuesday],[CLass2Tuesday]]]
```

This is my code (It's on Google App Engine, which may explain some oddities in the code...):

```
def get_classes():
    weekly_classes = []
    d = {1: 'Monday', 
         2: 'Tuesday', 
         3: 'Wednesday', 
         4: 'Thursday', 
         5: 'Friday', 
         6: 'Saturday', 
         7: 'Sunday'}
    yoga_classes = Schema.all() #appengine DB request
    if yoga_classes:
         #list that will be sent to template
        for n in range(1,8):
            day_classes = []
            for e in yoga_classes:
                if e.weekday == n:
                    day = d[n]
                    class_output = [str(e.name),
                                    str(e.teacher),
                                    str(e.description)
                                    ]
                day_classes.append(class_output)
            day_output = [day,day_classes]
            weekly_classes.append(day_output)
        self.response.out.write(weekly_classes)
```

Comment: This could be written much more succinctly, but shouldn't `day_classes.append(class_output)` have one more level of indentation?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks! Didn't quite solve the whole thing but removed some of the superfluous list entries. Care to give me any hints on how to make it more succinct. This is my very first solo project on my own since I did Udacity's online course CS253 so I'm happy for any pointers as to which direction I should head in :)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Actually, that indentation solved it all, except for one annoying thing. My DB table now consists of yoga classes Monday thru Thursday. However the list outputs  ['Thursday', []], ['Thursday', []], ['Thursday', []]] in the end. I suppose because range(1,8) makes it append until the iteration is done. How can I make it not append when there are no classes on that day?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make the days of the week your dictionary key and map each day to a list? The numeric keys in your dict don't really have any meaning as far as I can tell. You could fill the lists in your loop with something like `classes_by_day[day].append(class_output)`; then at the end you use [`items()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to convert to a list of tuples of the form `('Day name', [list of classes])`. You may need to sort afterwards and filter out empty lists, but your code will be much easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some more pythonic code, leveraging [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). The data is sorted by the day as required by `groupby()`, then grouped. I have found that any use of the range function indicates that you're doing something that is more C than python, and there's probably a cleaner way to do it. Note that the vast majority of this code is just setting up the dummy data to work with.

```
class Yoga():
    def __init__(self,weekday,name,teacher,description):
        self.weekday=weekday
        self.name=name
        self.teacher=teacher
        self.description=description
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s yoga with %s %s" % (self.name,self.teacher,self.description)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

# just make up some data to work with
yoga_classes = (Yoga(1,"dynamic","mary","6pm"),
                Yoga(1,"soft","susie","8pm"),
                Yoga(3,"hatha","bob","5pm"),
                Yoga(3,"hot","alice","7pm"))

daylookup = (None,"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
            "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")

import itertools
def get_classes():
    weekly_classes = []
    ycsorted = sorted(yoga_classes,key=lambda x: x.weekday)
    for k,g in itertools.groupby(ycsorted,key=lambda x: x.weekday):
        weekly_classes.append((daylookup[k],tuple(g)))
    return weekly_classes

import pprint
pprint.pprint(get_classes())
```

Comment: CaptainMurphy: WOW! :) I didnt notice this til today. Thanks for putting so much effort into answering this. I have to admit that I don't understand all of it, but I feel it is exactly where my "edge" is so understanding this feels like a good challenge for me. Have a great weekend!